# WTAI does not work from WebView (Android)

Tags: android, webview, wtai

Clicking on a link

```
<html><a href="wtai://wp/mc;8015551212">Click me to make a call</a></html>
```

in a WebView results in a "Page not found" error. Though the same link works just fine from the mobile browser. Any way to fix this?

**EDIT:**

```
String h = "<html><a href=\"wtai://wp/mc;8015551212;\">wtai</a></html>";
String g = "<html><a href=\"tel:5551234\">tel</a></html>";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    web.loadData(h, "text/html", "utf-8");
}
```

Comment: `is this right URL(\"wtai://wp/mc;8015551212\") ?`

Comment: Are you sure this url works in mobile browser?

Comment: fixed the URL - there are no backslashes in fact

Comment: @user370305: As far as I understand there is: http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2135-how-to-initiate-a-phone-call-from-your-mobile-website/

Answer (score 0):

This is the incorrect way of writing a tel WTAI link in Android.

```
<a href="tel:+27822222222">Call us now!</a>
```

is the correct way of writing this link.